# randomly assign 1,2, or 3 to unique character string

Tags: r, random

I have a character vector and I want to randomly assign numerical categories 1, 2, or 3 to each character string in the character vector. How can I do this in R

Input

```
Species
Species1 
Species2
Species3
Species4
Species5
```

Example output

```
Species   Category
Species1  2
Species2  1 
Species3  1
Species4  3
Species5  3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sample` :

```
set.seed(2020)
df$Category <- sample(3, nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
df

#   Species Category
#1 Species1        3
#2 Species2        2
#3 Species3        1
#4 Species4        1
#5 Species5        2
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Species = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Species1", 
"Species2", "Species3", "Species4", "Species5"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Should I use set.seed(2020) too?

Comment: If you want the results to be reproducible you can use any seed. If you want it random everytime you don't need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(Category = sample(3, n(), replace = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Species = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Species1", 
"Species2", "Species3", "Species4", "Species5"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```